# Adding rows to WordPress profile

Tags: wordpress, profile

I'm trying to add some more features to the profile in WordPress where it's possible to add some feature descriptions about education, with the following knowledge: cause, year, hours spend, toter and date.

Comment: I whould like something like this:
https://codepen.io/Living_Legacy/pen/xLJbyN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to add just profile fields, I would suggest using [WP Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-members/) or [Advanced custom fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) / [ACF PRO](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/) for this.